# How can I read barcodes without having the user focus a text box first?

Tags: c#, java, windows, delphi, barcode

I recently acquired a Metrologic Barcode scanner (USB port), as everyone already knows it works as a keyboard emulator out of the box.

How do I configure the scanner and my application so that my app can process the barcode data directly? That is, I don't want the user to focus on a "Text field" and then process the data when the KeyPress event fires.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually barcode scanners can be configured to send some characters before and after the string. So if you append eg "F12" before the barcode string, you can capture that and move the focus to the right field.

Check the barcode scanner manual how to do that.

Comment: Usually you *want* to have a text field anyway, so that users can manually enter the barcode if the scanning fails. That's why I think this is the best choice.

Comment: This is how we do it with cheque readers; whether they are keyboard wedge or USB, we configure them to send a start character sequence that isn't easily typed at the keyboard. When we see that sequence via the form's keydown method, we swallow those special keypresses and move the input focus to the desired edit box. Works pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

Although your barcode has a USB connector. It can be programmed as a Keyboard wedge or RS232.
See this page   http://www.instrumentsandequipmentco.com/support/faq-metrologic.htm
Where it says

***Q. What is the difference between USB Keyboard and USB Point-of-Sale?***
When the MX009 is set-up to communicate as a USB Keyboard, the scanned data will appear in the current application that is active on your PC. The data is entered just as if the keys were pressed on the keyboard. When the MX009 is set-up to communicate as a USB Point-of-Sale device, the data is transmitted to the USB port like RS232 data and the USB port must be configured like a COM port. The MX009 leaves the factory set for either USB Keyboard or USB Point-of-Sale.

When your program accepts RS232 you no longer need focus in a text field.

1. Reprogram your barcode as Point-of-Sale (RS232)
2. Reprogram to send a suffix usually - carriage-return/CR/$0D at the end of the barcode.

Look for the Carriage return to know when the complete barcode is available to your code.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess the easiest way to do this would be to intercept key-presses at a higher level, such as [PreviewKeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown.aspx) in winforms (or use `KeyDown` on the form, set `KeyPreview` to `true`, and use `e.SuppressKeyPress` to stop the key going down to the controls). There *might* be a direct API to the device; there might not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OnShortcut event on a form to intercept keyboard presses.
Check if the prefix you configured on the barcodescanner appears, and set as Handled al keypresses until you get the barcode scanner suffix. 
Within your Shortcut handler build up the barcode string

The following code is adapted from something I use myself, but is untested in its current form.

```
    // Variables defined on Form object
GettingBarcode : boolean;
CurrentBarcode : string;
TypedInShiftState: integer; // 16=shift, 17=ctrl, 18=alt

procedure Form1.FormShortCut(var Msg: TWMKey; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  Character:Char;
begin
  Character:=Chr(MapVirtualKey(Msg.CharCode,MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR));
  if GettingBarcode then
  begin
    // Take care of case 
    if (TypedInShiftState<>16) and CharInSet(Character,['A'..'Z']) then
        Character:=Chr(Ord(Character)+32);
    TypedInShiftState:=0;
    // Tab and Enter programmed as suffix on barcode scanner
    if CharInSet(Character,[#9, #13]) then
    begin
      // Do something with your barcode string
      try
        HandleBarcode(CurrentBarcode);
      finally
        CurrentBarcode:='';
        Handled:=true;
        GettingBarcode:=False;
      end;
    end
    else if CharInSet(Character,[#0..#31]) then
    begin
      TypedInShiftState:=Msg.CharCode;
      Handled:=True;
    end
    else begin
      CurrentBarcode:=CurrentBarcode+Character;
      Handled:=true;
    end;
  end
  else begin
    if Character=#0 then
    begin
      TypedInShiftState:=Msg.CharCode;
    end
    else if (TypedInShiftState=18) and (Character='A') then
    begin
      GettingBarcode:=True;
      CurrentBarcode:='';
      Handled:=true;
    end;
  end;
end;
```